# Sublime Text 3 - Fixing tabs once and for all

Tags: sublimetext3

I just created a new project, copied some file from an old projects where tabs were 4 characters

now I open the project it uses 2 characters per tabs althought my project settings clearly states 4 characters

this is not about indentation, this is about defining tabs = 4 and having tabs set as 2 characters

```
{
  "folders":...
  "settings":
  {
    "detect_indentation": false,
    "word_wrap": false,
    "tab_size": 4
  }
}
```

how can I fix this ?

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix inconsistent indentation of a project in Sublime Text 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50027395/how-to-fix-inconsistent-indentation-of-a-project-in-sublime-text-3)

Comment: no it's not, the prohject settings are not applied

Comment: The tab size affects the indentation; if Sublime is auto detecting that the indent is 2 characters, it will set the `tab_size` to 2 automatically. Are you sure that turning off detection doesn't solve your problem?

Comment: I changed my config, but still the same...some files has 4 characters tabs, other files have 2, this does not make any sens

Comment: I closed my project and reopened it, now all files have 2 characters tabs...wtf

Comment: I figured it out, it was a bloody .editorconfig file that was automaticaly created in my angular project

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, a .editorconfig file that was automaticaly created in my angular project with indent_size=2